# CSS Selectors - change width if last image id is X

Tags: css, css-selectors

i try now several hours to figure out how i could change the width of a class if there is a image id before the element.

Currently my code looks like that

```
<blockquote>
<img id="bp_avatar" src="...">
<p>Text</p>
</blockquote
```

The problem is now that the image is been dynamicly inserted, in some cases it will be there in some other it wont. I tried now to wrap the image inside the text, but to fit into it the blockquote p needs a width of 90%.

So here is the issue, it should be 90% if it's there and 100% if its not there.
I would like to use css instead of jquery, i found on w3 some documents about Level 4 Selectors and tried to use them, the goal was to apply the style if #bp_avatar is there.

So i tried ways like

```
#bp_avatar ~ #bluepostq blockquote p  {
width: 90%!important;
}


#bluepostq blockquote p! > #bp_avatar{
width: 90%!important;
        }
```

None of them worked yust nothing happens, i think i missunderstood something and hope someone could tell me what i have done wrong.

Comment: `id` should be unique for every image.. is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `~` is correct, but you just need to use it a bit differently:

```
p {
  width: 100%;
}
#bp_avatar ~ p {
  width: 90%;
}
```

This will make it so that `p` is 100% width but if it is preceded by `#bp_avatar` it will be 90%.

If you were attempting to limit it to only within a certain element (maybe `#bluepostq` which isn't in the sample html) that would go first in the selector:

```
#bluepostq #bp_avatar ~ p {
```

Additionally, if you know that the `p` will always be the very next element after the `#bp_avatar`, you can use the adjacent sibling selector:

```
#bp_avatar + p {
```

```css
blockquote{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
img{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#bp_avatar ~ p {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img id="bp_avatar" src="...">
  <p>Text</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
  <p>Text</p>
</blockquote>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezLaaoco/

Comment: Thank you this is working. So i guess my mistake was to add the blockquote before p? and as result he was not matching on the p because he needed a blockquote directly after?

Comment: Right, the other elements are contained within the blockquote so it needs to be first.